# how to google fusion provider not triggering GPS Provdier in outdoor location?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I am using google play services fusion provider to get location via locationclient.

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
 mLocationRequest.setPriority(
                LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
 mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

issues 
My application is not able to get GPS provider updates in "OUTDOOR" location
were as GOOGLE maps automatiicaly triggers GPS on an outdoor location.

I have also checked the lcoation settings in the phone all the options are checked

Am i missing some thing to obtain GPS updates

Comment: You need to add the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to manifest.And also please go through the online documentation for location client with example.

Comment: I have added fine location in manifest even then i am getting same issue

Comment: Since you have added the required permission you should start getting location updates. Kindly go through the online documentation for location client with example provided by google.

Comment: I have implemented using sample map only